# How to get my parent parent when i click the anchor inside the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is how the code was displaying:

```
<li>
<div data-trgtid="dom-target-15" class="anchor_div">
    <small class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="confirm" id="15" name="read" title="Read me"></a>
    </small>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

How can i get the `li` specificaly in javascript?
Please help.
my click in js is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".confirm").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        var tem_elid = 'dom-target-15';

        var pDoc = parent.parentNode;
        // var tem_elid = 'dom-target-'+id;
        // var dt_domid = document.getElementById(tem_elid).getAttribute("data-trgtid");

         alert(pDoc);



    });
});
```

Comment: do you have a click handler... if so `$(this).closest('li')`

Comment: what do you mean? sorry just new in javascript...

Comment: I have current code to get the anchor click
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".confirm").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent();

            var tem_elid = 'dom-target-15';

            var pDoc = parent.parentNode;
            // var tem_elid = 'dom-target-'+id;
            // var dt_domid = document.getElementById(tem_elid).getAttribute("data-trgtid");

             alert(pDoc);


            
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks too it help me figure out quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click handler, `this` refers to the clicked `anchor` element, so you can get the parent `div` to which the `anchor` belongs to by using [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) like

```js
$(function() {
  $(".confirm").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var tem_elid = $(this).closest('.anchor_div').data('trgtid');
    snippet.log('target: '+ tem_elid);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div data-trgtid="dom-target-15" class="anchor_div">
      <small class="pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="confirm" id="15" name="read" title="Read me">Read me</a>
      </small>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```